# Problemas Asunto Mail phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Tengo un problema debido a que enviando un correo con PHPMailer, me llega el mensaje, todo bien, a excepción de que el asunto y nombre del remitente me llega con este texto:  `=?utf-8?Q??=`

Pongo el código, a ver si ustedes encuentran alguna anomalía o solución, gracias!

```
$destinatario = "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mx";
$asuntoMail = utf8_decode("Petición por mail | www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mx");

require("function/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

$mail->From     = ($destinatario); 
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->AddCC($destinatario);
$mail->AddBCC("mail@maxilco.com");

// Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);     
$mail->Subject  =  $asuntoMail;
$mail->Body     =  'mensaje';

// Datos del servidor SMTP

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Helo = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->Host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Timeout = 60;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mx";  // Correo Electrónico
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Contraseña

if(!$mail->send()){
  echo "Ocurrio un error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo." intentelo nuevamente";
} else  {
  echo "<p>¡Correo enviado!</p>";
}
```

Comment: Prueba cambiando las variables por datos estáticos... algo como esto: `$mail->Subject  =  'Petición por mail | www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mx';`. Si te funciona, es un error con las variables

Comment: Gracias, pero lo acabo de modificar como comentas, pero me genera el mismo resultado!

Comment: has un print_r a ver que te muestra?
guardas el correo en la base de datos? que valor se guarda alli?

Comment: Hola Gabo, prueba actualizar phpmailler mediante composer, según veo el código debería andar perfectamente no veo cual es el inconveniente. puede que te hallas descargado la librería no oficial y por ahí esta generado un bug en alguna parte. composer require phpmailer/phpmailer    https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: Gracias Matias, fue precisamente el tema, al actualizar la versión se soluciono el problema, excelente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente uso la versión 5.5 que puedes descargar [del GitHub oficial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Tras descargar el paquete completo, descomprime y copia a tu proyecto **solo la carpeta** `src`. Luego creas un archivo `mail.php` (*o el-nombre-que-prefieras.php*) y usa el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'tu_ruta/src/Exception.php';
    require 'tu_ruta/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'tu_ruta/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // use $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
    $mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl is depracated
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "remitente@dominio.com";
    $mail->Password = "password_remitente";
    $mail->setFrom('remitente@dominio.com', 'Tu_nombre');
    $mail->addAddress('destinatario@dominio.com', 'Nombre_destinatario');
    $mail->Subject = 'Petición por mail | www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.mx';
    $mail->msgHTML("Hola Se ha generado una nueva petición por Email");
    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('ruta/file.php'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    $mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/proof.jpg'); //Attach an image file

    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo "Ocurrio un error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo." intentelo nuevamente";
    } else  {
        echo "<p>¡Correo enviado!</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Excelente se logro solucionar con esto, muchas gracias! estaba usando una versión más antigua de PHPMailer

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido!