# ¿Por que ya no puedo Enviar correos desde php con PHPMailer?

Tags: php, javascript, phpmailer

hace tiempo realice un proyecto en php que enviaba correos desde php con PHPMailer, intento hacer uno nuevo y resulta que ya no envía los correos, e vuelto a correr el proyecto anterior y tampoco envía los correos, alguien tiene alguna solución?

este es el código utilizado

```
  require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail= new PHPMailer();
      //////////////esto es para la conexio
      $mail-> isSMTP();  //utilizara este protocolo
      $mail-> SMTPAuth=true; //si se va a auntentificar;
      $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';//tipo de seguridad que se utilizara para gmail
      $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
      $mail->Port='587';   //puerto
      $mail->Username='ejemplo@ejemplo';//desde donde enviarmemos
      $mail->Password='pass';//Tu contraseña de gmail

      //////////////agregamos el contenido que debe de llevar
      $mail->setFrom('correo quee envia','ALERTA CODIGO DE EMERGENCIA');  ///es para dar vista al correo



 $mail->addAddress('correo al que se enviara','Directivos');//aquineress//aquine enviamos el correo

 $mail->Subject='CODIGO ROJO';
 ///cuerpo donde se puede utilizar texto plano o HTML
 $mail->Body="aqui dejo el cuerpo del mensaje";

   ///////agregamos un tag
 $mail->IsHTML(true);//habilitamos enviar contenido en html

 $mail->send();
```

Comment: ambos proyectos con la misma versión de php?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo si la misma versión php7

Comment: Es posible que se traté de un error de versión. Revisa la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239281/problemas-asunto-mail-phpmailer/239404#239404). Espero que te sirva.

Comment: @DjCrazy muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te sirvió la información de la respuesta no olvides marcarla como útil, esto nos ayuda a ambos y a la comunidad en general.